# terraform: merging dynamic block

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl

Given the following resource block:

```hcl
resource "azuredevops_variable_group" "secrets" {
  project_id   = ...
  name         = "my-secrets"
  description  = "..."
  allow_access = true

  key_vault {
    name                = "my-akv"
    service_endpoint_id = azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.dev.id
  }

  dynamic "variable" {
    for_each = [
        "secret-1",
        "secret-2",
        "secret-3",
    ])
    content {
      name = variable.value
    }
  }
}
```

I need to set one more variable to this resource that is static. How should I merge a dynamic block? something like:

```hcl
merge (
  dynamic "variable" {
    for_each = [
        "secret-1",
        "secret-2",
        "secret-3",
    ])
    content {
      name = variable.value
    }
  },

  variable {
    name  = "secret-4"
    value = "foo"
  }
)
```

Adding another variable block after the dynamic block will raise `Error: "variable.0.value": conflicts with key_vault`.

Comment: You would probably need to convert your current secrets from a `list` into a `map` and then `merge`. Would that be ok?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Does that mean the `merge` function only works on maps ?

Comment: Yes; you would need `concat` for two lists. You cannot append a `map(string)` to a `list(string)` without a data transformation.

Comment: You can't "merge" dynamic blocks. Can you please explain better what do you want to achieve?

Comment: This error message about it conflicting with `key_vault` suggests that something else is going on here. In your example I see a `key_vault` block, and the error message seems to be saying that you can't have both a `key_vault` block _and_ a `variable` block which has `value` set. Just writing an additional `variable` block would be a valid way to achieve this syntactically, but in order for it to be valid per the provider's validation rules you'd need to remove the `value` argument from the block.